# HTML section and div fixed size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to fix the height of a div inside a section to 100px. However, no matter what I try, the height reverts back to 'auto' and re-sizes depending on the amount of content in the div.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<section id="social" class="tab-content active">
    <div id = "socialDiv"></div>
</section>
```

and here's what I've tried so far

CSS:

```
social{height:100px; line-height:20px;overflow:hidden;}
.socialDiv{height:100px !important; line-height:20px;overflow:hidden;}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.socialDiv').css({'height':100+'px'});
$('.socialDiv').height( 100 );
```

Unfortunately none of these work. I'd appreciate any and all help on this.

PS. I don't know if this will matter or not, but this is part of a Chrome extension and this section is part of a popup window that displays during execution.

Comment: Your html code don't match the css or jquery.

Comment: sorry. typo. theres 3 such sections, accidentally copied the css for the wrong section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixing `id` (`#`) with `class` (`.`)

Your class is `tab-content` but you're trying to change the id `social` on both js and css.

Try:

```
$('.tab-content').css({'height':100+'px'});
$('.tab-content').height( 100 );
```

Comment: you sire, are a lifesaver. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome @Irtza.QC :) If my answer helped you, please consider vote 1+ and accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark in the middle of the vote arrows, tks !

Comment: @PedroLobito. you should suggest  `$('tab-content').children()...` or `$('#socialDiv')...`